# Why java string method return null as string?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, null, return

This happened in a spring-boot application that used java version 1.8(java8). In a normal console application of java 14, it worked fine.

I had two methods related to a JWT filtering class which is extended by the "OncePerRequestFilter" class.

```
private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String jwt = getJwt(request);
        if (!jwt.equals("null") && okenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
            .....
            .....
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

expected **jwt** variable value was a token or null object. For checking that previously used `jwt != null` and that always gave true. It worked as expected when only changed that to `!jwt.equals("null")`.
According to this, getJwt method always returns a String object even it is null. How can explain this? Is there a way to return a null value instead of "null"?

Comment: Can't reproduce: Tested on Java 1.8 and Java 11, `public static String returnnull() { return null; }` then `if (returnnull() != null) { System.out.println(1); }` have no output. Is `String jwt` is really a string with 4 letter "null"?

Comment: @GenoChen, I have updated the code for more understandability. I have tried the same way in java 14 and got the same result as you. And it was the expected one. But here, something has gone wrong and I need some explanation for that. I think the answer to your last question can be found when checking the equals method.

Comment: I forget one thing. If `String jwt` **is really** `null`, then `jwt.equals()` will throw an NPE then the execution will go to `catch` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there was some mistake when debugging which caused to produce this problem as this way. 
For the login/sign-in request, frontend application has been passed the user credentials with Authentication header as `Bearer null`. Then the **getJwt** method is returned the sliced string of "null" to the other method. It was never executed the `return null` line.